# Cannot create entity hierarchy using LUIS API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, botframework

We want to create an entity hierarchy using the LUIS api. As per [the API docs](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de46a/console), we need to create a POST to the Create Entity Extractor endpoint with the JSON body:

```
{
  "Name": "EntityName",
  "Children": [
    "a","b","c"
  ]
}
```

However, when we run this request, LUIS only has a new entity called "EntityName", without any children. It is as if the children array is ignored. Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: Can you check if the children are added on LUIS.ai with your app ID?

Comment: @MokhtarAshour They are not. That's the issue.

Comment: Contact the support with the issue. Include a sample request/response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a surprisingly obvious but unexpected one. We did not realize that LUIS.ai exposes not 1 but 3 endpoints to CRUD entity extractors.

We were using the [entities](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de46a) endpoint. Seems like this endpoint is only intended for a flat entity structure.

Instead, we should have looked at the [hierarchicalentities](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/57d9362db7efca106034584b) endpoint.

Composite endpoints would naturally use the [compositeentities](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/57d9362db7efca106034584d) endpoint.